# Set Package User Variable Value in Integration Services and Run Package C# LoadFromSqlServer

Tags: c#, ssis, package, ssms

I have packages that I imported to Integration Services. I have them all set up and I have mapped them to run. My issue is that I am trying to programmatically pass a value to my User Variables in the package.

I have a `Start Date` and an `End Date` that I have to populate, but I have not been able to find anything regarding what I am doing. Can anyone help?

I am new to using `LoadFromSqlServer` and am not really sure if there is anymore information that you may need to help, but if you ask I will be more than happy to edit my question and add what is needed.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**---EDIT---**

Here is the error i am getting by using this bit of code:

```
Application app = new Application();            
Package package = new Package();
Variables variables = package.Variables;

package = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\File\\Path\\" + paramName, ".", "UserName"
, "Password", null);

variables["User::START_DATETIME"].Value = startDate;
variables["User::END_DATETIME"].Value = endDate;

DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
```

Here is the error:

```
Additional information: The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt 
is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during 
execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have 
changed or the variable is not being created.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to find the issue with my question. It is rather silly but still a solution.

In my code I was using

```
Variables variables = package.Variables;
```

Before I was actually attaching a package to my `package` variable.

Switching my code around to call the variables after the package was being attached to my variable worked. The new code looks like this:

```
Application app = new Application();            
Package package = new Package();

package = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\File\\Path\\" + paramName, ".", "UserName"
, "Password", null);

Variables variables = package.Variables;
variables["START_DATETIME"].Value = startDate;
variables["END_DATETIME"].Value = endDate;

DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the varibles into SSIS Package by:

```
Package package = null;

//Load the SSIS Package which will be executed

package.Variables["User::StartDate"].Value = '2014-01-01';
package.Variables["User::EndDate"].Value = '2014-01-10';
```

**EDIT**
1. Check if there is no typo:

```
if (package .Variables.Contains["StartDate"])
{
...
}
```

2. Ensure that the SSIS service is running
3. Also you can try to use Dispenser class:

   package.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("StartDate", variables)
   package.Variables["User::StartDate"].Value = '2014-01-01';
   variables.Unlock()

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately this is what i have currently tried to use and I get an error saying that it cannot find the variable name in the list of variables. Any ideas why this may be? I added the full error above in my question.